# Tips create an installer for .NET applications

Tags: c#, windows, installation, setup-deployment

I have created two desktop applications in C#.  I now want to deploy both as part of a single installation executable (EXE).

Do you have any suggestions on how to start?  Which technologies should I use?  Are there any good tutorials and/or templates online that can get me started?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Merge Modules?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243945(VS.60).aspx

You can include multiple merge modules in a single MSI installation.